# Why is Backup Migrate advanced options link going to content page?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, upgrading, backups

See video: http://screencast.com/t/PqKnaYbB5

I am using backup/migrate and when I click advanced options it just takes me to the content page. Also having a issue with clicking the configuration link for CKE Editor and it goes somewhere else. Any ideas why Drupal 7 would do this?